# mod_rewrite advice

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I was wondering if you could advise if there is a more efficient way of writing what I have below? Could this be achieved in the 1 rule?

```
RewriteRule ^search/(cars|boats|plant)/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/type-([0-9]+)/price-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ search.php?category=$1&location=$2&type=$3&minprice=$4&maxprice=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(cars|boats|plant)/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/type-([0-9]+)/?$ search.php?category=$1&location=$2&type=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(cars|boats|plant)/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ search.php?category=$1&location=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(cars|boats|plant)/?$ search.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Also, I am having difficulty obtaining a friendly URL after a form is submitted. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'd be better off just writing one rule to redirect from /search to search.php, and then parsing the rest of the URI there? (I.e. redirect to search.php?q=REST_OF_URI_GOES_HERE)

Comment: Hi Dav,

Thanks for your reply. Im not too sure how this would work? Ok, so if I redirect /search to search.php and parse the URL to get the variables passed, do I redirect to friendly URL using php?

Ho would the friendly URLs work without the rewrite rules?

Thanks

Comment: Friendly URLs on the pages, or in the address bar? You should be able to use friendly URLs on the pages already (that's why you have the rewrite, after all).